# Problem on displaying not maximized windows

Tags: 14.04, unity, window

I use `Ubuntu 14.04`. Recently, probably after last update, I encounter with a problem when OS shows not maximized windows, popup notes or right click menu. I upload two screen shots:

1- When I moved cursor above browser tab:
[image]

2- When `GIMP` window is not maximized:
[image]

How I can solve this problem?